# Creating generic template class to sort different classes by variables

Tags: c++, sorting, templates

I am able to read the file and populate the vector, respectively.

Is there a way to create a template to sort individual classes according to a criteria?
The method I using is tedious, and I have to create a lot template classes to fit each vector.

I need some idea on create a generic template

```
//consist if accessors and mutator x and y
vector<Point2D> point2d;
//consist if accessors and mutator x and y and z
vector<Point3D> point3d;
//consist if accessory and mutator 2 Point2D point
vector<Line2D> line2d;
//consist if accessory and mutator 2 Point3D point
vector<Line3D> line3d;
//sort_crit is a global variable that change according to user menu
//sort_order is a global variable that change according to user menu (ASC or DSC)
if(sort_crit == "X-Coordinate") {
    sortByX(point2d, point2d.size(), sort_order);           
}
```

My data

```
Point2D, [3, 2]
Line3D, [7, 12, 3], [-9, 13, 68]
Point3D, [1, 3, 8]
Line3D, [7, -12, 3], [9, 13, 68]
Point3D, [6, 9, 5]
Point2D, [4, 8]
Line3D, [70, -120, -3], [-29, 1, 268]
Line2D, [7, 12], [-9, 4]
Line3D, [25, -69, -33], [-2, -41, 58]
Point3D, [6, 9, -50]
Point2D, [12, 80]
Point2D, [9, 8]
```

My current template only work for Point2D

```
template <class T>
void sortByX(vector<T> a1, int size, string type) { 
if (type == "ASC") {

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++) {

        for(int y=0; y<size-1; y++) {

            if(a1[y].getX()>a1[y+1].getX()) {

                int tempx = a1[y+1].getX();

                a1[y+1].setX(a1[y].getX());

                a1[y].setX(tempx);

                int tempy = a1[y+1].getY();

                a1[y+1].setY(a1[y].getY());

                a1[y].setY(tempy);
            }
        }
    }
} else if (type == "DSC") {

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++) {

            for(int y=0; y<size-1; y++) {

                if(a1[y].getX()<a1[y+1].getX()) {

                    int tempx = a1[y+1].getX();

                    a1[y+1].setX(a1[y].getX());

                    a1[y].setX(tempx);

                    int tempy = a1[y+1].getY();

                    a1[y+1].setY(a1[y].getY());

                    a1[y].setY(tempy);
                }
            }
        }
}
    for(int x=0; x<size; x++) {
        cout << a1[x] << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear if you have multiple different sort criteria or not.

Comment: It's also impossible to suggest a generic implementation without you showing us the interface for your various classes.

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` is generic sort that allows you to provide a custom sorting criterion.

e.g., for some container of points, lines, etc, `l`:

```
sort(begin(l), end(l), [](auto& a, auto& b)
{
   return a.getX() < b.getX();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to create separate comparator classes for each of the respective sort orders that will work generically for all of the respective types which can be passed to the built-in `std::sort` algorithm.

```
template<typename T>
class ByXAscending {
    bool operator()(T const &lhs, T const &rhs) const {
        return (lhs.getX() < rhs.getX()
                || (lhs.getX() == rhs.getX()
                    && lhs.getY() == rhs.getY()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why roll your own sorting function? Try something like this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Point2D
{
    Point2D(int x=0, int y=0) : x(x), y(y) {}
    int x;
    int y;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Point2D &p)
{
    os << "{" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}";
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<Point2D> points;
    points.push_back(Point2D(3, 3));
    points.push_back(Point2D(27, 5));
    points.push_back(Point2D(7, 4));
    points.push_back(Point2D(13, 26));
    points.push_back(Point2D(9, 5));


    cout << "Before sort:" << endl;
    for (const auto p : points)
        cout << p << " ";
    cout << endl;

    sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [](const Point2D &l, const Point2D &r)
        {
            return (l.x<r.x);
        });

    cout << "Sort by x:" << endl;
    for (const auto p : points)
        cout << p << " ";
    cout << endl;

    sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [](const Point2D &l, const Point2D &r)
        {
            return (l.y<r.y);
        });

    cout << "Sort by y:" << endl;
    for (const auto p : points)
        cout << p << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```